# How to get lastindex of a character in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, indexof

I am getting index of a particular character in a string but not getting last index.I am using jquery function.

For example:
"abch/" by index of method I am getting the index of '/',But for "aa/aaaee/" i want the index of last '/'.I have used lasytindex of but it is not working.

My code:

```
if (request.term.IndexOf("/") == (request.term.length - 1)) {
                        var term = request.term.slice(0, -1);
}
```

Comment: Use **[.lastIndexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp)**. In your case `request.term.lastIndexOf("/")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.lastIndexOf()`:

```
request.term.lastIndexOf("/");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wvbhg/7/)**

Comment: it was not working only because of case sensitive.I was using LastindexOf.@Milind Anantwar

Comment: @sona:Yeah.. was guessing that it was a typo. using lastIndexOf is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.@Milind Anantwar

Answer (score 1):

Use [`lastIndexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_lastindexof.asp) method.

`request.term.lastIndexOf("/")`

Answer (score 1):

Following line return you last index

```
var lastindex = str.length-1;
```